# Using @property and @synthesize with ivar implicit creation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Ok, so lately I got this presumable bad habit of declaring my class properties with `@property` create getters and setters with `@synthesize` and simply use them anywhere I need them as `self.name` without having a reference to the inner ivar (let `@synthesize` do its work)

Now, of course this doesn't allow me to access the inner ivar (eg. `name_`) but from what I've coded so far, I didn't really need it. For read-only properties I don't use `@synthesize` but implement the getter myself.

Everything seems fine, but somehow I've got the feeling that this is not right because all the open source libraries I've had a look over, also declared the ivar and used it throughout the code. `@property` + `@synthesize` and no ivar its definitely the lazy choice, but what are the drawbacks? Can someone give me some advice?

Also, I've read that, as a general advice, it's OK to use `self.propertyName` anywhere in your class code except the `dealloc` and `init` methods. But as long as you make sure the object is initialize:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

and you remove all key-value observers before calling `[super dealloc]` everything should be fine. Right?

Comment: If you mark the property as readonly, synthesize will only generate a getter. There is nothing wrong with being lazy as long as the behaviour is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well the `@synthesize` will create the inner ivar with the same name as the property:

```
@synthesize name;

- (void) dealloc {
   [name release], name  = nil;
   [super dealloc]
}
```

Or give the inner ivar an other name:

```
@synthesize name = _name;

- (void) dealloc {
   [_name release], _name  = nil;
   [super dealloc]
}
```

I use the `self.name` in the init but not in the dealloc and seems to work great.

Comment: Upvoted, but there's really no reason to set your ivars to nil in `-dealloc`.

Comment: For iOS that could mean waiting for week(s) until your new version is uploaded, and getting horrible ratings. And it requires having a crash report system. I'm not sure if crashing early and often in production is a good idea. It also depends on the type of app I guess.

Comment: @Jano I don't know if your comment is directed at me or at @rckoenes, but I don't follow it either way.  Not setting ivars to nil in `-dealloc` is not generally going to lead to frequent crashes, unless you are in the habit of referencing your ivars in that method after you release them.

Comment: @Seamus Well, bugs shouldn't happen but they do. After much discussion, some nil http://zathras.de/blog-defensive-coding-in-objective-c.htm and others don't http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1423/dont-coddle-your-code I do both with a release macro.

Answer (score 5):

It comes down to which version of the Objective-c runtime you are building for: [Modern or Legacy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html).

- The **Modern version** supports "instance variable synthesis for declared properties".  ie. there is no need for you to define an instance variable for each `@property`. The runtime will take care of creating one for you.  By default the ivar will be named the same as the `@property`.  You can change the ivar name by using the format `@synthesize propertyName = iVarName;`
- The **Legacy version** does not support ivar synthesis and therefore you must define an ivar for storage of your `@property`.

*iPhone applications and 64-bit programs on Mac OS X v10.5 and later use the modern version of the runtime.  You should assume that every other platform uses the legacy version.*

What are the drawbacks?  Well, the biggest one is portability - By not defining the ivars your code can run on fewer platforms e.g. it won't work on OSX 10.4.  You also lose some control/flexibility & might inadvertently run into name collisions with sub- & super- classes.

It's important to remember that you should [deallocate properties that you have synthesized](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW16) with `@synthesize`.  Properties are not automatically released - you should `release` any synthesized property that is not marked `assign` (don't release any properties marked assign).

N.B. For extra credit you can tidy up your read-only properties.  There's little reason to write your own accessor and not use `@synthesize`.  Simply define your property as read-only & optionally what to call the getter `@property(getter=isIntReadOnlyGetter, readonly)`

Comment: If your property is readonly, why would you declare the getter explicitly?  Is is just so that the ivar and the getter have different names?

Comment: There are a few reasons to set the name of the getter to be different from the ivar or property name. One of the most common is readability.  Say you have an instance variable that stores whether or not an object is `BOOL green`.  Rather than the getter just being `- (BOOL) green` it is more understandable if use use `- (BOOL) isGreen`.

Comment: I understand why you might have getters and setters with different names; I'm asking about the case where you have only a getter, because you have declared you property to be readonly -- the "property name" is then not actually useful as a property name.  If your purpose is just as a way to name your ivar, I can understand, though personally I would be inclined to say `@property (..., readonly) BOOL isGreen` and `@synthesize isGreen=green`.