# Do properties implicitly create a class member of that name and type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I was looking through a Storyboard tutorial here: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

When I noticed that the author created properties with a name and type without creating the member variables in the interface section.
It was to my understanding previously that the @property/@synthesize declaration in objective C only created a getter / setter for a member variable of that name and type.
I didn't think that the variable was implicitly created with the @property/@synthesize.
Is the class member implicitly created? 
If not how does this code work:

```
@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *game;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rating;

@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using @property and @synthesize with ivar implicit creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912188/using-property-and-synthesize-with-ivar-implicit-creation)

Comment: Short answer: yes, `@synthesize` creates an ivar with the same name as the property. The `@property` declaration by itself does not. This is clearly and explicitly stated [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9).

Comment: Another duplicate, possibly a bit better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238009/property-declaration-and-automatic-backing-storage-allocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's implicitly created with the `@sythesize` keyword if an ivar of the specified name doesn't already exist. For example, given the above properies:

```
@synthesize name; // Creates an instance variable called "name"
```

Alternatively...

```
@synthesize name = _name; // Creates an instance variable called "_name"
```

Which means you no longer need to specify ivars in your class' `@interface`.

Comment: It's not really "implicit" -- creating the ivar is [one of the stated purposes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9) of the `@synthesize` keyword.

Comment: I agree; the docs state it explicitly. Speaking strictly from a code syntax point of view, I would describe the creation as "implicit" with the @synthesize keyword.

Comment: Small side note: this only works in the "modern" Objective-C runtime. The modern runtime is used on 64-bit OS X and iOS. 32-bit OS X still requires you to explicitly declare ivars even for @synthesized properties.